# How to sort controls at runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, controls, runtime

How to order Controls at runtime in ASP.NET
for instance I have three text boxes in my web page in the following order

- textbox1
- textbox2
- textbox3

I want the order of these controls to be changed depending on the user preferences

- textbox3
- textbox2
- textbox1

that is just an example, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution and I will explain it in detail

create a "panel control" and called it "myPanel" and put in this all controls you want to resort

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="dock1" runat="server">this is first module</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="dock2" runat="server">this is second module</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="dock3" runat="server">this is third module</asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

the output will be the following

this is first module

this is second module

this is third module

so what should I do to change their order, lets see
I have created more three panels to act like a containers for the docks
my code will be like this

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="container1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="container2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="container3" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="dock1" runat="server">this is first module</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="dock2" runat="server">this is second module</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="dock3" runat="server">this is third module</asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

in the code behind I have something like this

this will remove dock1 control from mypanel and put it in container3

```
    Control myCtrl1 = myPanel.FindControl("dock1");
    Control containerCtrl1 = myPanel.FindControl("container3");
    myCtrl1.Visible = true;
    myPanel.Controls.Remove(myCtrl1);
    containerCtrl1 .Controls.Add(myCtrl1);
```

and you can manage these thing depending on user preferences from a database or a cookies

best regards

Comment: what is the purpose of 'myCtrl1.Visible = true;' I ended up having to add that too because my panel kept disappearing

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI framework can do that for you. Check out this [demo](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/sortable/) and the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortables/sortable) for the same.

Comment: thanks, thats true however it works in client side , this consumes system resources I think, because the whole page will be loaded then jQuery will hide the object that I want hide and resort what I want to sort, thanks

Comment: If you want to do anything at runtime on asp.net it's best to do it clientside.  Your clients are powerful enough to run a modern web browser, arent they?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use third-party controls like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com). More precisely DockZones.
Otherwise you'd have to create your own pagebuilder with this functionality.

Comment: thanks, Telerik will work and I have used it in my X job ,I think it has some problems (1)it is not free (2) it is more than what I want (3)I feel that it consume system resources (just a feeling :))

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue and resolved by using ".Controls.AddAt" and specifying an index for the order you want it to appear.

so to make my chart appear first in the panel i change:

```
GraphPanel.Controls.Add(GE.GetChart(t13));
```

to:

```
GraphPanel.Controls.AddAt(0, (GE.GetChart(t13)));
```

and your example to order textboxes in order of 3, 2 then 1 becomes:

```
Panel1.Controls.AddAt(0,(TextBox3));

Panel1.Controls.AddAt(1,(TextBox2));

Panel1.Controls.AddAt(2,(TextBox1));
```

Answer (score -2):

For a very simple proof-of-concept, you would need some kind of backing store like a database table that stores UserID, Ordinal, and AscxFileName. In SQL you could run a query such as:

```
SELECT AscxFileName FROM tableControls WHERE UserID=@UserID ORDER BY Ordinal
```

Then with the result set:

```
while(IDataReader.Read())
{
    Control myControl = Page.LoadControl(IDataReader["AscxFileName"].ToString());
    myPanel.Controls.Add(myControl);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this didn't solve the problem, because I want to resort the controls not loading them in order

Answer (score -2):

Grab all the IDs of the textbox controls and store them in an array. Then just do a reverse sort:

```
Array.Reverse( mytextboxArray );
```

Comment: what I want is resorting the controls positions in the page
thanks for trying to help

Comment: You need to do this first. You can then spit the controls out dynamically on the page and avoid the need for either a database or a JavaScript solution.